# Is there a best practice for handling browser resizing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, cross-browser

I feel like GMail is an excellent example of best practices in action, but I'm looking for a more theoretical code-based approach. CSS? JavaScript? jQuery? Let's hear it.

Comment: i like the resizing in http://www.w3.org/ , especially when you resize the window to really small and it becomes mobile

Comment: That even works without JS! Must have taken many, many hours of horrid CSS hacking. Of course, they *are* the W3C...

Comment: @MvanGeest — no, they just use (draft) CSS Media Queries.

Comment: @David Dorward: I didn't know they existed. Do you know if IE9 will support them (I couldn't find that anywhere)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most web application use proper document layout and CSS to make the flow work itself out naturally when the user resizes the browser window, without executing any script at all. This is exactly what the CSS properties `display`, `position`, `float`, `clear`, etc. are for.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more about "proper document layout"?  I find your answer to be vague and not really helpful.

Comment: By 'proper document layout' I mean: Use structural markup as it is intended, then apply CSS to style it. Make good use of the various options you have to provide a document that naturally adapts itself to the given window size and font. This means, among other things, that you should avoid absolute positioning, specify sizes in em rather than pixels where this makes sense, don't use tables for layout unless you absolutely have to, try not to insert structural elements for the sole purpose of creating a visual effect (although this is often the only way to achieve what you want).

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you have to do on window resize...

Usually most applications and websites use browser resize event for changing layout or increasing/decreasing font size when user changes browser window size.

[Check this article out](http://www.themaninblue.com/writing/perspective/2004/09/21/)...

Comment: Umm. The vast majority of websites don't do anything special with browser resize events. Off the top of my head, I can think of only one website that does (and that is because it has two layouts, isn't designed for desktop browsers, and had the resizing trick added on as an afterthought to make things a little nicer for users who do try to visit it with a desktop browser)

Answer (score 0):

you could do something like [this](http://jsbin.com/ezima/2/).

The idea is you make a large wrapper (`#main`,the lightest one) and you place 2 divs inside:`#left` and `#right`.

left is a fixed width div `width:200px` and floats left `float:left`.

right is liquid so no width, but to prevent `#left` from overlapping you give `#right` a margin of the width of `#left` -> `margin:0 0 0 200px`.

To prevent `#right` from being to small you give it a minimum width `min-width:400px`. Now when you resize the window `#right` will resize along until `#right` gets at `400px` then the scrollbars will be visible